# Building a house during times of economic upturn

Tags: investing, real-estate

Since 2008 the aftermath of the recession, the economic crisis has turned from recession into a rise and better economic times. In some places, in western european cities, this means housing prices being almost the same as before the economical crisis of 2008, resulting in a stagnation of housing prices.

Is this a good time to build a house? Considering that wages and prices are higher in times of high employment than times of unemployment and considering that the price for a m2 is much higher than in times of recession, allowing for more economical expences to be used on better quality equiptment and building materials. On the opposite, the mortgage from the real estate loans are higher during economic recessions juxtaposed with times of economical wellbeings.

I plan to build a house as a home for 10 years+ and for an investment in my future. The area around is popular, but not much new is being build so new houses with a good energylabel is popular among newcomers. I'm sure I can sell it again, but the general question is where the best investment comes from - building during recession or during financial upturns?

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: is this self financed

Comment: `...and for an investment in my future.` [Some food for thought](https://jlcollinsnh.com/2013/05/29/why-your-house-is-a-terrible-investment/)

Comment: As a side note to this - lots of land in our neighborhood during the recession were priced at $15k, the same lot today is $60-75k. Another thing is that during a recession it can hit home builders pretty hard, so while I have no data to back this statement up, it stands to reason that building a house during a recession will give you the better long-term investment. Now if your question was about building vs buying used during an upturn then the argument for building becomes a lot more viable and that's the reason we built - it was the same price in our area to build vs. buy used...